# Complex INSERT INTO SELECT statement in SQL

Tags: sql, insert, sql-insert

I have two tables in SQL. I need to add rows from one table to another. The table to which I add rows looks like:

```
timestamp, deviceID, value

2020-10-04, 1, 0
2020-10-04, 2, 0
2020-10-07, 1, 1
2020-10-08, 2, 1
```

But I have to add a row to this table if a state for a particular deviceID was changed in comparison to the last timestamp.

For example this record "2020-10-09, 2, 1" won't be added because the value wasn't changed for deviceID = 2 and last timestamp = "2020-10-08". In the same time record "2020-10-09, 1, 0" will be added, because the value for deviceID = 1 was changed to 0.

I have a problem with writing a query for this logic. I have written something like this:

```
insert into output
select *
from values
where value != (
select value
from output
where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from output) and output.deviceID = values.deviceID)
```

Of course it doesn't work because of the last part of the query "and output.deviceID = values.deviceID".
Actually the problem is that I don't know how to take the value from "output" table where deviceID is the same as in the row that I try to insert.

Comment: Tag your question with your DBMS. Provide the `values` table sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `order by` and something to limit to one row:

```
insert into output
    select *
    from values
    where value <> (select o2.value
                    from output o2
                    where o2.deviceId = v.deviceId
                    order by o2.timestamp desc
                    fetch first 1 row only
                   );
```

The above is standard SQL.  Specific databases may have other ways to express this, such as `limit` or `top (1)`.